# How to stop automatic sending of phishing emails from web application?

Tags: php, email, web-applications, phishing

I have some web applications,hosted in different domains.

But users are reporting that they are getting phishing emails from those.
What may be the reason behind that and most importantly,how would I stop these?

Can HTTPS/SSL help me out?
Plz help.

N.B. : I'm using PHP,MySQL here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No way of answering this.  The phishing emails might not even be coming from your sites, but someone is just using your domains in the from field.

Comment: No, everybody can simulate email sending from any host, for example with php `mail()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They basically don't receive emails for exactly those domains. A phishing email can be send from any domain with any email address you want.

It's also good to check your servers for malicious scripts that are inserted there without your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Mihai,certainly will be checking that.Apart from that,can SSL installation be fruitful in these scenario?

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Look into SPF Records, DomainKeys and other domain validation techniques that SMTP servers use when receiving emails to validate the request. If the email is sent from an unknown source, it will simply reject, or mark the email as spam, instead of delivering it into your inbox. This is usually used to prevent your emails from going into spam, but I think will also help you in this situation.

Comment: @Gavin users don't have emails on his domains, they are simply users. You cannot control an email sent to an user.